# Mudar a cor de fundo do do panel ao clicar

Tags: javascript, css

> O código acima funciona como um accordion, é o mesmo code do accordion do Bootstrap. Gostaria de saber, como fazer para que o
> usuário ao clicar no "Panel-Heading", ele ficar com o fundo verde, e
> quando voltar ficar com o fundo branco, sem afetar o heading de baixo.
> Ou seja: Antes de clicar ele estará com o fundo branco. Depois que
> clicar ficará com o fundo verde.

```html
<head>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Paulo poderia ser mais específico na sua pergunta pois vejo três situações que possam vir a fazer sentido com o seu exemplo mas não sei qual apresentar.

Comment: Ao clicar para expandir, mudar a cor do panel-heading, e quando encolher a cor voltar ao  normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara achei meio estranho a forma como vc montou a estrutura para mostrar os cards, mas para trocar a cor é só usar esse CSS. Eu usei o seletor `[aria-expanded="true"]` para pegar quando o elemento está aberto e coloquei a cor.

```
  .accordion-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] > .row .card {
    background-color: green !important;
  }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vc tb pode usar o evento jQuery com o trigger da classe `.show` para adicionar uma classe extra. Mas achei com CSS mais simples de fazer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
  .accordion-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] > .row .card {
    background-color: green !important;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">Reclamações abertas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center">5 vendas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ele nao mudou a cor, nao fez nada. Quero que ao expandir ele mudar a cor do panel-heading

Comment: @Paulo acho que entendi, ajustei a resposta e agora está trocando a cor do elemento correto

Comment: @hugocsl, existe mais uma possibilidade de resposta, três ao total. Existe a possibilidade de somente o item clicado ter a cor de fundo alterado. Eu pedi esclarecimento mas o autor deu uma resposta pouco explicativa.

Comment: so mais uma pergunta, pq ele esta mudando somente o card, e para min mudar p panel-heading todo, e nao somente o card

Comment: @Paulo é só adicionar `.panel-collapse.show .card {
    background-color: green !important;
  }` no CSS

Comment: @AugustoVasques não espere perguntas "perfeitas" por aqui. Até pq nem toda resposta é "perfeita"... E para mim, particularmente, o que o AP escreveu foi o suficiente para entender e bolar uma resposta.

Comment: É justa a orientação. Obrigado.

Comment: Galera obrigado pelas, resposta, deu certinho aqui!